# Scheduling job biweekly in Azure Databricks

Tags: cron, expression, azure-databricks, scheduling

I want to schedule a job in databricks notebook that starts running from 24th March 2022 and runs every 14 days after that.
So the days would be 24th march, 7th april, 21st april, 5th may. Like this.

0 30 0 22/14 * ?
I have made this cron expression to do this task. But not sure whether it is correct or not.
Here 0 30 0 is specifying the time and 22/14 means it will run on 22nd of the month with increments of 14 days. * is for month and ? for day of week.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, The cron expression as per your requirement might not be possible. your expression `0 30 0 24/14 * ?` may trigger the job on 24th of every month and expression like this `0 30 0 24/14 3 ?` will trigger only in 3rd month i.e, March. Using cron expressions it might only possible to trigger on every same date in the month and not after every 14 days.

So, As a workaround you can Execute the job from ADF and trigger the ADF pipeline after every 14 days starting from 24th like below using schedule trigger.

[image]

In this pipeline Execute the existing databricks job by following this [tutorial](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure-blog/leverage-azure-databricks-jobs-orchestration-from-azure-data/ba-p/3123862) by @**Leo Furlong** and @**ClintonWFord**.